# Android - Dialog dismiss

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-dialog

I have created a simple login where the user enters his details and using AsyncTask it comapares user input to SQLite database if its correct it will start intent of Main activity.

Problems:

1. Loading progressDialog doesnt dismiss if the user password/username is incorrect but shows the else statement toast when incorrect password/username

In the Login class on the OnClick i have declared a new LoginTask of the users input here is my AysncTask

```
    private static class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog pd;
    String username, password;
    private final Context context;
    Intent log;
    // private final WeakReference<Context> reference;

    private LoginTask(Context context, String username, String password) {
        this.context = context;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

        //final Context context = this.context;
        //Controller handler = new Controller(this.context);

        pd = new ProgressDialog(this.context);

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //super.onPreExecute();
        pd.show(this.context,"Authenticating account ...", "Please wait ...");
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... p) {
        //final Context context = this.context;
        Controller handler = new Controller(this.context);
        handler.open();
        if (!handler.executeLog(username.trim(), password.trim())){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        pd.dismiss();
       // super.onPostExecute(result);
       // final Context context = this.context;
        Controller handler = new Controller(this.context);
        handler.open();

            if (result == false) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed, Incorrect Username/Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                handler.close();
                Intent log = new Intent(this.context, MainActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(log);
                ((Activity)context).finish();
                Toast.makeText(context, "You have successfully logged on, " + username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Hi, it may be more appropriate to ask separate questions for each of your issues, that way you can ask the question using code specific only to each problem. As it stands your question is a little bit hard to understand, and also fairly broad.

Comment: @Sippy I have updated it now

Comment: replace your this.context with context or your activtiy name if it is in the same activtiy.

Answer (score 1):

Change this :

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
      //super.onPreExecute();
       pd.show(this.context,"Authenticating account ...", "Please wait ...");
       pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
}
```

By this:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // super.onPreExecute();
    this.pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside( false );
    this.pd.setCancelable( true );
    this.pd.setTitle( "Authenticating account ..." );
    this.pd.setMessage( "Please wait ..." );
    this.pd.show();

}
```